# How should a train move between stops given the engine has power P?

Tags: calculus, optimization

So I've been playing a lot of Factorio recently, and I was thinking about how the trains move, and I came up with something that I have no idea how to solve.

A train is on a track of length D, at each end of the track the train's velocity must be $0$. How should the train move as a function of $x$ (the position on the track between $0$ and $D$) to minimise the journey time given that the maximum power of the engine is P? I will greatly appreciate answers with resistive forces taken into account.

I have tried to use naive calculus of variations on this problem, but I end up with a nonsensical solution where the acceleration is $0$. I also tried it with a had a resistive force of $-\mu \dot x$, still nonsensical.

Another thing I tried is to split the problem into an acceleration and deceleration phase of movement (with a discontinuity in acceleration at the phase boundary) but my calculus of variations-fu is not strong enough to prove that this must be the time-minimising solution.

Any suggestions / things I need to add to make it soluble? Or just a godly answer to assuage my curiosity?

Answer (score 2):

I love Factorio.

I'm going to expand a bit more conceptually on Ross Milikan's answer. I think you may be over-thinking some parts of the problem, and *under*-thinking other parts. I do that often, too, and think it's a sign of a more general kind of confusion—so, yes, this post will be long. :)

I don't believe your question can be answered without knowing a couple of other things first. Let's figure out what we need to know given your question...

> How should the train move as a function of $x$ (the position on the track between $0$ and $D$) to minimize the journey time given that the maximum power of the engine is $P$?

Power is measured in $\text{watts}$, which are $\text{joules-per-second}$, and $\text{joules}$ is the unit of energy. Thus, $P$, the maximum power of the engine, is answering the question "What is the maximum amount of energy that the engine can use in one second?"

This doesn't really help us with the movement of the train. That is, if the train weighed $1,000,000~\text{lbs.}$, then the engine might have to use its maximum energy, $P$, to move the train very slowly. On the other hand, if the train weighed $100~\text{lbs.}$, then the engine could use its maximum energy to move the train very quickly. We need thus need some relationship between $P$ and the $\text{mass}$ of the train, because the mass tells us how fast $P$ will make the train go. Thus:

- We need to know the $\text{mass}$ of the train

Now, let's say we know the mass. Knowing the mass of the train and maximum power of the engine tells us how quickly the engine can *accelerate* the train. That means—given the mass, how fast can the speed of the train increase? This seems a little closer to what we want, but it's not quite there. Ideally, the answer would just be: "Well, set the engine to maximum power and that's it", because that would **always** minimize the time. But, presumably, we want our train to... you know... not crash into point $D$, be able to take wide turns, etc. (for simplicity, let's assume a straight track).

That brings us to the next issue. We know $P$, and, assuming we know $m$ (the mass), we know how fast the train can accelerate. Now we need to know how fast the train can *decelerate*. The brakes are our other limiting factor. If the brakes work really, really well, we pretty much *can* just set the engine to max speed. If they don't work at all, then we can only set the engine to low (we need enough time to brake before the train gets to $D$). Thus:

- We need to know the mass of the train
- We need to know how quickly the train can decelerate

There are some other things, too, depending on how detailed we want to be. We'd need to know things like:

- The terminal velocity (how fast can the train go before breaking down, before the track melts, etc.)
- How fast the train can go while taking a turn

In short, though—just knowing $P$, it's impossible to tell what the most time-minimizing actions would be. In terms of Factorio, though—those trains stop instantly. Just plow through at max acceleration (at least assuming you only have two stops, where each end has the end of a track).

Comment: Ah, knew I was forgetting something, I am a fan of unit masses :P Also Cracktorio is love Cracktorio is life.

Answer (score 1):

What is the limitation on braking?  Basically you want to accelerate at full power, then brake at full power, timing the transition so you arrive at the destination at zero velocity.  I will assume that for braking you have a maximum deceleration of $b$ available.  Having a power limit says $P=\frac {dE}{dt}=\frac d{dt}\frac 12mv^2=mva$ where $E$ is kinetic energy, $m$ is the mass of the train, $v$ is the velocity, and $a$ is the acceleration.  This would say you can get infinite acceleration at zero velocity, so you need to impose some other limit for the startup phase.  I would suggest you impose an acceleration limit of $c$ when that results in less power than $P$.  This would give and acceleration profile of $$a=\begin {cases} c&v \lt \frac P{mc}\\
\frac P{mv}&\text{later}\\-b & \text{braking} \end {cases}$$  You might also have a maximum speed on the train which would make a zero acceleration phase in the middle.  Now choose the time to start braking so that you cover the right distance when the speed drops to zero.

Comment: I probably should have added braking in, they even have braking tech in Factorio! So the braking power probably effects the solution strongly. Would your solution for acceleration give the time minimising solution? How'd I prove that it is the best solution?
What would happen if the train has to use the engine in reverse to slow down? i.e no brakes.

Comment: I claim it is the time minimizing solution because you are always going as fast as you can or as fast as you can afford.  If the braking uses engine power you can adapt the acceleration phase approach for the braking period.  The symmetry then says you start braking at the center of the run.

Comment: At this [link](https://www.quora.com/Does-constant-value-of-mechanical-power-mean-constant-acceleration) the physicist says "so you start with a jerk of infinite acceleration and then taper off". I take that to mean that, ignoring friction, etc., you don't need to limit acceleration to $c$. It seems like the key factor is whether Factorio models friction and other real world effects (mechanical latency in the drive system, chemical latency in the combustion, electrical/mechanical latency in the engine control system, etc.)